# Take 11th page results using google custom search API in java (Not in same day and limit is not exceeded)

Tags: java, api, google-custom-search

I am using Google Custom Search API to get results from Google in response to a query in Java.I used following code for that.

```
            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
                    + apiKey + "&cx=" + engineID + "&q=" + keyword
                    + "&hl=en&start=101");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
```

I could take page 1 to 10 without no problem. But when I take result from 11th page it gave an error. For 11th page I used `"&hl=en&start=101"` .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cx=001736963393770650507:vah--basm5u&q=medical&hl=en&start=101
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at readURLtoTxt.CustomSearchAPI.main(CustomSearchAPI.java:52)
```

UPDATE:

I alredy know ,I can take only 100 results per day using 10 pages. But my problem is not that. My limit is not exceed. I want to take 11th page results. Then it gave above error.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
                    + apiKey + "&cx=" + engineID + "&q=" + keyword
                    + "&hl=en&start=101");
```

So, I need to do any changes in this code part?

Comment: Read the answers to the linked question (or many other questions with the same topic on stackoverflow, google groups, etc.): even though it seems to be not clearly stated in the api reference, the search queries are limited to the top 100 search results (10 pages with 10 results equals 100 results) for the free service (no workarounds, paid service might be an other case).

Comment: I understood your point. Thank you very much.